# How does Whatsapp store the numbers?

Tags: android, whatsapp

so here is my doubt.how does the whats-app store the info about our phone number which we used at the registration.so when we insert a new number at the registration,what happens ? 
where does the number store? and how does whats app retrieve our number when we enter our number later.please explain as simple as possible;thanks.

Comment: You better ask this question to WhatsApp developers.